# How to do an update on mysql database for increment values

Tags: mysql

I will give a small exemple for my problem.
I have two tables in my database.

"Car" with the rows: "id","name".
"Seats" with the rows: "cid","weight".

The weight for the seats referees to the order of the seats.A car can have from 0 to n seats.
My problem is that i have seats with the same weight on a car.

I need to do an update for every car where two or more seats have same weight.

CAR

```
--------------------------
     id     |  name
--------------------------
     1      |  ford
--------------------------
```

SEATS

```
-------------------------------
     cid    |   name   | weight
-------------------------------
      1         Seat1  |    7
      1         Seat2  |    1
      1         Seat3  |    7
      1         Seat4  |    3
      1         Seat5  |    2
      1         Seat6  |    3
      1         Seat N  |   N
-------------------------------
```

And i need to have:

CID is the CAR id

SEATS

```
-------------------------------
     cid    |   name   | weight
-------------------------------
      1         Seat1  |    0
      1         Seat2  |    1
      1         Seat3  |    2
      1         Seat4  |    3
      1         Seat5  |    4
      1         Seat6  |    5
      1         Seat N  |   N
-------------------------------
```

The query will run on a very big database and will affect many rows, so it is need to be fast.

I have done the join on the tables, but i don`t know how to make the complete update method.
The  INNER JOIN is needed for this.

Comment: Your example is wrong. `cid` has a seat value and is not related to the cars table

Comment: Sorry, i have updated

Comment: You need to user user-defined variables in query but performance is no guaranteed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user-defined variables in order to achieve a serial no for your weight column

```
update t 
join (
select `cid`, `name`,@rank:= @rank + 1 rank
  from t join  
  (select @rank:=-1) t1
  order by `cid`, `name`
) t2
using(`cid`, `name`)
set weight = t2.rank
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5f54/1)

or if you need to a serial weight no for each car group then you can do so

```
update t 
join (
select `cid`, `name`,
  @rank:=case when @group = cid
  then @rank + 1
  else 0 end   rank,
  @group:=cid
  from t join  
  (select @rank:=-1,@group:= 0) t1
  order by `cid`, `name`
) t2
using(`cid`, `name`)
set weight = t2.rank
```

### [Demo serial per group](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/174eb7/1)

Comment: @florian.ioan if it works then mark it as accepted for reference [*how does accepting an answer works*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)